# Defining a linear function on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

I was curious about how to define a linear function in a vector space whose basis is not countable. In this case, to have a concrete example, I though about the sequence space in $\mathbb{R}$, that is,

$$\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}=\prod^{\infty}\mathbb{R}$$

Imagine that we wanted to define a linear function $A_{i,j}$ that for a sequence $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ it acts as a swap elements operator:

$$x=(x_1, x_2, ..., x_i, ..., x_j,...)$$

$$A_{i,j}(x) = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_j, ..., x_i,...)$$

If the basis is not countable, how can we express $x$ in terms of a linear combination of the elements of the basis $\{e_1, e_2, ...\}$ i.e.: as a vector of some coordinates? And, without this notation, how can we express our function $A_{i,j}$? In the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is be trivial to construct a swap matrix that represents such function. Is it even possible to find a (infinite) matrix form in this other case?

**Edit:** thank you very much for the comments. One of them made me realise that maybe my choice of the function $A_{i,j}$ is not the best for the question I have, since it only acts on a finite dimensional subspsce of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$. In this sense, a better example could be a function $B_i$ that adds a $0$ at the i-th position of a sequence, that is,

$$B_i(x) = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_{i-1}, 0, x_i,...)$$

Comment: Usually in infinite dimensional vector spaces, the notion of basis becomes not that interesting anymore, one uses [orthogonal series/systems](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Orthogonal_series#:~:text=The%20active%20development%20of%20the,functional%20analysis%2C%20quantum%20mechanics%2C%20mathematical) instead. Also, infinite matrices tend to not get used. One looks at these more from the viewpoint of operators as from the viewpoint of matrices.

Comment: Linearity is just defined as $f(\lambda x+\mu y)=\lambda f(x)+\mu f(y)$. For the finite dimensional case, you probably prove in linear algebra that they coincide with matrices.

Comment: On another note, why is expressing $x$ as a linear combination a problem? After all, by definition every element of a vector space is a _finite_ linear combination of basis elements. I suspect a lot of confusion here arises from the fact that you have not found a basis (although this might prove to be difficult).

Comment: But for using such a system you need to have a definition for what an infinite sum is. In this example, I only present the vector space $(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N},+,\cdot)$ - I do not attempt to work with Schauder basis or anything similar

Comment: Also notice that the vector and matrix representations become even less useful if the basis is uncountably infinite.

Comment: @user3141592 usually only finite sums are considered, also an infinite dimensional basis is a set of vectors such that every vector can be written as a FINITE linear combination of those vectors.

Comment: @BenSteffan That's a great point I was missing, thank you. Nevertheless, I unfortunately still don't see how that can help in finding a way to represent an arbitrary linear function such as the proposed $A_i,j$ in this space

Comment: @VincentBatens Thank you for the input! Nevertheless, how can one represent this type of seemingly "inoffensive" functions in these spaces in a way that we can work with them?

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "in a way that we can work with them" and "how can we express our function $A_{i,j}$"? You have already expressed it, in a way that's *much* clearer than writing down an infinite matrix! Can you give an example of a problem that you think could be solved by finding a better representation? Typical applications of matrices in finite dimensions are things like calculating determinants or inverses, but in infinite dimensions those are pretty hopeless in general.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I know that my question can seem a bit "broad" in that sense: it's difficult to make it more explicit without directly knowing an answer to it. But, for instance, the matrix form formalism in finite dimensional spaces is a way to express this type of functions that allows you to obtain other deeper results, much more difficult to obtain than by manually defining the function by writing a sentence of what it does - a different sentence for every function. I wondered whether there's any representation/formalism in infinite dimensional spaces to achieve such type of advantages

Comment: You are talking about a non-countable basis, so writing it as $\{e_1, e_2, ...\}$ is a bad idea.

Comment: I note that any such $A_{i,j}$ only acts on the $\mathbb{R}^{\max(i,j)}\ $ subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$.  So, perhaps it is smarter to think of $A_{i,j}$ as the identity except on that subspace and then write the matrix on that subspace (using a $\max(i,j)$-element basis for that subspace)?  Of course, one can then make this "stupid" by (1) pick $A_{i,j}$, (2) pick an infinite basis starting with $\hat{x}_i, \hat{x}_j, \dots$ and then (3) have the resulting matrix be the two dimensional swap.

Comment: @EricTowers good point, thanks! Maybe then the functions $A_{i,j}$ were not the best example - I edited the question consequently

Comment: If you want to see a concrete example of a vector space with a non countable basis, you could think about the polynoms with real coefficients. It is indeed a vector space on $\mathbb{R}$ (the sum of 2 polynoms is a polynom as is the product of a polynom by a real value). And $(1, x, x^2,\dots,x^n,\dots)$ is a natural basis. And a polynom is a **finite** linear combination of elements of that basis. And you can still define the derivation (which is a linear function over the polynoms space) by its action on the vectors of the basis: $\left(x^n\right)'=n\times x^{n-1}$. What is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is not (usually) required that it is possible to represent a linear function from one vector space $V$ to $W$ as a matrix.  It just needs to have these two properties:

$$f(u+v) = f(u) + f(v)$$

$$f(\lambda v) = \lambda f(v)$$

These can be compressed into one rule as in Vincent Batens' comment.

For a finite dimension space and some countable infinite cases, it is possible to represent the linear function as a matrix but this is not required.  An arbitrary uncountable dimension vector space only has a basis if we accept the Axiom of Choice.

An interesting example of a linear function which cannot easily be represented as a matrix is the Fourier transform.

Answer (score -1):

Note that your $B_i$ is not linear, because $B_i(x+y)\not = B_i(x) + B_i(y)$.

Differentiation over the space of all differential functions is one common example of a linear map over an infinite dimensional vector space.

Comment: I edited a typo in the definition of $B_i$ to solve the issue with linearity. This should have been posted as a comment instead of as an answer, since it is not directly addressing the scope of the question

Comment: Are you sure you meant to ask for an uncountable space? $B_i$ only makes sense if the sequence is countable.

Comment: why is that? note that $B_i$ is not performing a change of coordinates of a vector in our vector space, but of elements in our infinite sequences